# Fastest and cleanest way to update an environment variable for the new Bash instances?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I am trying to create / update an environment variable for every bash instances.

Basically I would like the result of `export MSBuildSDKsPath=/opt/dotnet/sdk/$(dotnet --version)/Sdks`
to be applicable to every bash instance.

The only solution I found is a bit dirty is to put it at the end of the `.bashrc` file in my home folder but I am not sure this is the right way of doing.

I read in other places that sometimes it should be put in `.profile` or `.bash_profile` but if those files are changed within the same user session and then I start a new bash instance, `$MSBuildSDKsPath` is not updated accordingly.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)?

Comment: @danzel didn't know that there was something, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next comment exists in `~/.profile` file by default:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.
```

That's why it was not work for you.

Additionally, `.profile` contain next code by default

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This code invoke your `~/.bashrc` if it exists.

For your purposes, adding variable export to the end of `.bashrc` file, I think, is a best solution.